# PNG Plane picture showing over other planes out of order in render view

Tags: rendering

[image]

The bottom to the “tower” is appearing in front of the mountains in render view.

However, it is supposed to be behind them, and is aligned that way in 3d view.

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide the .blend file or take some screenshots of your setup?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GPfJ2Y7

Here are the screenshots, and below is the blend file

https://file.io/WjJ7UK

Edit: turning transparency off of the tower png plane fixes the issue, but then the tower is not transparent, which is needed. Don't know if it is related.

Comment: the .blend file link is broken.

Comment: Sorry, used a bad website. Here it is:

https://gofile.io/?c=ACVpiS

Comment: Visibly textures are needed for the rendering, but your file does not include the textures (not packed in the blend file). So nothing is visible. And you should preferably use this link to upload blend files https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/